# TYPO3 - How to retrieve/update own table in extension?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-tca

I would like to create an extension like **tt_news** , so i need to connect with my own tables .
So how to write data fetching and insertion to the custom table

Comment: Are you gonna to do this with 'old school' or with `Extbase` ?

Answer (score 4):

In general, creating the extension from the scratch doesn't make a sense especially when you're learning.

#### Old school

For 'old school' extension it's the best way to install [Extension Kickstarter](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kickstarter).

It will help you to create tables, all required structure etc. Also will allow you to extend existing tables (ie. you can use it to modify tt_news tables and add custom filds without touching the  tt_news' sources)

You should choose this way especially when you want to impact with some *well-known* extension written the same way.

All methods for working with DB can be found in the [API](http://typo3.org/api/typo3/classt3lib___d_b.html)

#### MVC - Extbase

If you're more familiar with MVC it would be better to use [Extension Builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder)

It's the funnier way and allows to create extension faster, however it's less documented and more abstract.

It has also built-in modeler for creating your DB tables (Models) and creates set of default `actions` for the listing, displaying, modifying and removing records from your table. (with the bit of experience simplified version of the tt_news ca be created in few hours)

I generally prefer [extbase](/questions/tagged/extbase) and [fluid](/questions/tagged/fluid)  for my new exts, esspecialy as it's some kind of preparation to work in the future with [flow3](/questions/tagged/flow3), but you need consider which points are more important to you.

Comment: I agree with Marcus - definitely go for Extbase / Fluid if possible.

Comment: I have done a plugin for the fontend with Classes and Controllers using Kickstarter and maulay edited to achive MVC(With the help of an article). But that is done with the tt_content table alternation. But now i need my own table and those entries will be displayed over the LIST menu and Frontend + myplugins Admin menu under the WEB. like WEB->MyPlugin Admin.-------------------------------- So I'm stuck with adding content to the new table. am not familar with this TCA. is there any online tutorial or pdf?

Comment: Och gee... the worst scenario I think... you choose the mixed way, so it's even hard to find any examples for you. The best solution now is: create some other extension with kickstarter with **very similar** name, create there the required tables and other stuff, and then just copy the TCA settings, sql file etc etc into your MVC-kickstarted ext of course you'll need to change the table names, but it's better than adding whole the structures from the scratch.